# MODX: MIGX Extremely slow load times

Tags: content-management-system, modx

I'm currently implementing MODX into a current site.  ([click here](http://citycafescranton.com/menu/))

As you can probably tell, loading the site takes an absurd amount of time for something mostly textual.  It loaded very quickly before I was using this CMS, so I'm assuming that it's just taking a very long time to request information from my database.

Here's how I have it set up:  Each item under the category is included like this:

```
[[!getImageList?
&tvname=`lunchSoups`
&tpl=`menuItem`
]]
```

So, seeing as I have both Dinner + Lunch menus as well as all of these items, I end up with 14 requests.  Is this what's slowing my page down, or is it just the amount of information?  How can I reduce the load time?

Edit: I've taken out the ! in getImageList, so now it caches.  The initial load is still extremely slow, though.

[image]

Edit: TPL Chunk:
I thought maybe the conditional type statements might be slowing down the website, but they seem to be the same speed without them.

```
[[+item:notempty=`
<h2>
<span>[[+item]] / <span>[[+price]]</span>
</h2>
`]]

<h3>
<span>[[+description]]</span>
</h3>

[[+addItem:notempty=`
</br>
<h2 style="font-style:italic; font-size: 13px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; text-align: center; line-height: 1.2;">
[[+addItem]]
</h2>
</br>
`]]
```

Comment: Can you share your `tpl` chunk? If you have snippets nested in that it can really slow things down. Also, are you processing thumbnails? That can be slow.

Comment: @okyanet , added the tpl

Comment: It looks like you might be using a separate call to getImageList for each of your menu categories, up to 14 in total? That might the problem, although your content is lightweight and 7 seconds still seems like a long time. Wrap all your snippet calls in the Executioner snippet to see which are the slowest, then report back: http://modx.com/extras/package/executioner